# Passing State to onEnter

Tags: react-router

Specific to React Router v2, I have a "private" route configuration that has the following:

```
onEnter: function(routerState, replace) {
  if (!routerState.session.authenticated) {
    replace({}, "/login");
  }
},
```

How can I pass in a `session` object to `routerState`?  A custom `<Router render={...} />` doesn't work because `render` occurs *after* `onEnter` has been called.